# How to `select` to an array of strings

Tags: powershell

When I use the `Select-Object Name` CmdLet it seems to create a new object with a single `Name` property on it.

I often want to pipe this selection to other CmdLets but they often take just a string.

How can I easily get a bunch of objects and say "Select only property x and just the property values into an array or collection of just its values"?

Comment: @JohnLBevan Why not as a formal answer? You could line your pockets with up-votes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `ExpandProperty` parameter for this.  This switch means that instead of returning an object with properties as listed on the (default) `-Properties` parameter, the value of the single property listed under `-ExpandProperty` parameter is returned.

NB: You can also use the alias, `expand` for this parameter.

Example:

```powershell
Get-Process | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProcessName
```

Related documentation:

- SS64: https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html
- MS Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object?view=powershell-3.0

Comment: Not to badmouth SS64, but why would people link there instead of to the [actual documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object?view=powershell-3.0)?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers fair point; edited to include your MS link.  I always go for SS64 first since generally I find those explanations/examples clearer (personal preference).