# PowerShell Get-ADGroup Display Issue

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing a script with a GUI for work and I have an Issue that I am having trouble getting past. I am trying to get the Department to show all of our departments in a combobox but when the script pulls the departments from the AD it also displays the `@{Name=` before every department name (see image below).

Here is the block I am having issues with

```
$DepGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Our Departments,DC=ourDC,DC=com" |
             select Name | Sort -Property Name
$DepBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DepBox.Width = 136
$DepBox.Height = 20
$DepBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(95,53)
$DepBox.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$DepBox.DropDownStyle = 'DropDownList'
$DepBox.Items.AddRange($DepGroups)
$Form.Controls.Add($DepBox)
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \`select\` to an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691978/how-to-select-to-an-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Uusing the | Select pipe will return an object with the selected attributes in it, in this case just the Name.

You should use ( < obj > ).Name to just get the value of the Name attribute.

i.e.

```
$DepGroups = (Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Our Departments,DC=ourDC,DC=com").Name | <Any additional sorting>
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I needed Thank you very much!